# Regex to match scientific notation

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match numbers in scientific notation (regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658662/1285620)):

```
scinot = re.compile('[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)')
re.findall(scinot, 'x = 1e4')
['1e4']
re.findall(scinot, 'x = c1e4')
['1e4']
```

I'd like it to match `x = 1e4` but not `x = c1e4`. What should I change?

**Update**: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152597/extract-scientific-number-from-string) has the same problem: it incorrectly matches `'x = c1e4'`.

Comment: @sunkuet02 Clarified why that answer doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Blender trying to match numbers in scientific notation, but not match variable names containing that pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing scientific notation sensibly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638565/parsing-scientific-notation-sensibly)

Comment: @BogdanVasilescu You really need to learn how to use Google

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for the unnecessary downvote. That's the post I started from, linked where I say "regex from here".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add anchor at the end of regex and alternative space or equal sign before the number:

```
[\s=]+([+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+))$
```

Comment: Thanks @Toto. That doesn't match `x = 1e6`.

Comment: @BogdanVasilescu: Do you mean it doesn't match the whole string `x = 1e4` or `1e4` alone?

Comment: I meant it doesn't match `1e6` from `x = 1e6`. Sorry about the confusion. `re.findall('^[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)$', 'x = 1e6')` returns `[]`.

Comment: @BogdanVasilescu: Remove the caret (start of string) and add `[\s=]`, see my edit.

Comment: I'd prefer if `=` is not part of the match; right now I get `['=1e6']` for `x=1e6`.

Comment: @BogdanVasilescu: Add `+` after character class `[\s=]+` and use a capture group, see my edit, the result will be in group 1.

Comment: what to change here, so that it also matches normal number like '-200.200' ?

Comment: @Eular: Just make the last part `(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)` optional: `(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?` (or remove it)

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `[^\w]?` to exclude all alphanumeric characters that precede your first digit:

```
 [+\-]?[^\w]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)
```

Technically, the `\w` will also exlude numeric characters, but that's fine because the rest of your regex will catch it.

If you want to be truly rigorous, you can replace `\w` with `A-Za-z`:

```
 [+\-]?[^A-Za-z]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)
```

Another sneaky way is to simply add a space at the beginning of your regex - that will force all your matches to have to begin with whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @Akshat. Your suggestion still matches `c1e4` unfortunately. Also, if I add a space (nice idea!), I won't be able to match `x=1e4` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`scinot = re.compile('[-+]?[\d]+\.?[\d]*[Ee](?:[-+]?[\d]+)?')`

This regex would help you to find all the scientific notation in the text.

By the way, here is the link to the similar question: 
[Extract scientific number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152597/extract-scientific-number-from-string)

Comment: Not really: `re.findall('([-+])?(\d+)(\.\d*)?[eE]([-+]?\d+)*', 'x = c1e6')` returns 
`[('', '1', '', '6')]`

Comment: Try now @BogdanVasilescu

Comment: still not what I need. `re.findall('[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*[Ee](?:\ *[-+]?\ *[0-9]+)?', 'x = c1e6')` incorrectly matches `['1e6']`