# Regex to match scientific notation of numbers but not other letters

Tags: regex, numbers, scientific-notation

I want to write a regex to match all positive double numbers with maximum 2 digits after decimal point.

My first approach was this:

```
^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$
```

it works fine for most cases but not for scientific notations, for example `10000000` when it's written as `1.0E7`.

I've found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668588/regex-to-match-scientific-notation) and I made adapted it to my case resulting:

```
[\\s=]+([+]?(?:0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d{1,2}))$
```

but now it returns false for a lot of "good" values.

Any idea how to make it match only positive numerical values with 0 to 2 digits after the decimal point but also the scientific notation of the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You copied the exact regex from the other answer which asked for more requirements i.e. matching equation. Removing those with a bit modification you could try:

```
^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)?$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/1sVb9Q/1)

Comment: Missing `1e1` or `.1e1`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming zero is not a positive number, you can use

```
^(?:0\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?)|[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?$
```

where

- `(?:0\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?)` matches a positive number smaller than 1 with at most 2 decimal places
- `[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?` matches a positive number equal or larger than 1, with optional up to 2 decimal places
- `(?:e[+-]?\d+)?`optionally matches the scientific notation

Caveats:

- no leading zeros allowed
- no `.` without decimal places allowed (can be fixed by using `\.\d{0,2}`)
- more decimal places are possible due to the e-notation (e.g. 1e-3)
- i-Modifier should be used
- you might just want to use your languages ability to parse and compare float values

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ljOaIb/1/