# Using Regex and or in order to get rid of unwanted characters

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm getting verry confused with the regex and I need help.
I have the following string:

```
x='def{{{12.197835/// -0.001172, 12.19788 7.3E-5, //+{{12.196705 -1.7E-5, 12.196647 -0.001189///}}}Def'
```

This string is part of cell in specific column in pandasdataframe. each cell has different unwanted characters, mainly letters and "/" or "{".

**I want to have this output:**

```
x='12.197835,-0.001172, 12.19788,7.3E-5,12.196705 ,-1.7E-5, 12.196647 -0.001189'
```

(get rid of anything that is not a digit, beside if is a number with "-" before or E- which is "E-" with digit before.

I have used this expression in order to ger inly the digits:

```
print(re.findall(r"\d+\.*\d*",x))
>>>['12.197835', '0.001172', '12.19788', '7.3', '5', '12.196705', '1.7', '5', '12.196647', '0.001189']
```

but my problem is that this expression does not preserve the '-' or the 'E'.
I have tried to save them by the following expression:

```
print(re.findall(r"\d+\.*\d*",x) or (r"^-?[0-9]\d+\.*\d+*\[E-]",x))
```

but I get the same output:

```
>>>['12.197835', '0.001172', '12.19788', '7.3', '5', '12.196705', '1.7', '5', '12.196647', '0.001189']
```

I thought maybe is because i'm using or and then it alreay satisfy the first condition so I tried also "and" but that gives very weird results:

```
>>>('^-?[0-9]\\d+\\.*\\d+*\\[E-]', 'def{{{12.197835/// -0.001172, 12.19788 7.3E-5, //+{{12.196705 -1.7E-5, 12.196647 -0.001189///}}}Def')
```

My end goal is to get the first string with only digits, '-' and E that has after it '-'  (the desired output)

```
x='12.197835,-0.001172, 12.19788,7.3E-5,12.196705 ,-1.7E-5, 12.196647 -0.001189'
```

Comment: You can use OR like `re.findall(r'pattern1|pattern2', x)`. Not like `re.findall(...) or (r'...', x)`

Comment: Why not use a proper parser for that format?

Comment: @superb rain this is part of lambda function running on very long pandas dataframe. if you have any idea how to do it better I would love to hear :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried now re.findall(r'\d+\.*\d*|^-?[0-9]\d+\.*\d+*\[E-]', x) but got error "error: multiple repeat at position 27" , maybe I don't understand you correct

Comment: Replace `+*` with `*`. Also, `^` matches at the start of the string, you need to remove the anchors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to match scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668588/regex-to-match-scientific-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```py
import re
x='def{{{12.197835/// -0.001172, 12.19788 7.3E-5, //+{{12.196705 -1.7E-5, 12.196647 -0.001189///}}}Def'
print(re.findall(r'[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?', x))  # Extracting all numbers into a list
# => ['12.197835', '-0.001172', '12.19788', '7.3E-5', '12.196705', '-1.7E-5', '12.196647', '-0.001189']
print(",".join(re.findall(r'[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?', x))) # Creating a comma-separated string
# => 12.197835,-0.001172,12.19788,7.3E-5,12.196705,-1.7E-5,12.196647,-0.001189
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ry71u9) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GDZ3mu/1).

**Regex details**

- `[+-]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of `e` or `E` followed with an optional `+` or `-` and then one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope** this help you (without using regex).

```
x='def{{{12.197835/// -0.001172, 12.19788 7.3E-5, //+{{12.196705 -1.7E-5, 12.196647 -0.001189///}}}Def'

x=x.replace('{','').replace('}','').replace('def','').replace('Def','').replace('/','').replace('  ',' ').replace(' ',',').replace(',,',',')

print(x)
```

**[Result]:**

> `12.197835,-0.001172,12.19788,7.3E-5,+12.196705,-1.7E-5,12.196647,-0.001189`

Comment: thank you for your answer, the reason I don't use replace is because the characters are not always the same in my case and that was only one example, i'll edit my post