# Using regex on Python to find any numerical value in an expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get all numerical value (integers,decimal,float,scientific notation) from an expression and want to differentiate them from digits that are not realy number but part of a name. For example in the expression below.

```
230FIC000.PV>=-2e3 211FIC00.PV <= 20 100fic>-20.4 tic200 >=45 tic100 <-2E-4 fic123 >1
```

the first 230 is not a numerical value as it is part of a tag (230FIC100.PV).

Using the web tool [regexp.com](https://regexr.com/) I come up with the following expression that works for the expression above.

> `(?!\s)(?<!\w)[+-]?((\d+\.\d*)|(\.\d+)|(\d+))([eE][+-]?\d+)?(\s)|(?<!\w)[0-9]\d+(?<!\s)$`

However when I try to use the above expression in python re.findall() I receive as result a list with 5 tuples with 6 elements on each.

```
import re
pat = r'(?!\s)(?<!\w)[+-]?((\d+\.\d*)|(\.\d+)|(\d+))([eE][+-]?\d+)?(\s)|(?<!\w)[0-9]\d+(?<!\s)$'
exp = '230FIC000.PV>=-2e3 211FIC00.PV <= 20 100fic>-20.4 tic200 >=45 tic100 <-2E-4 fic123 >1 '
matches = re.findall(pat,exp)
```

The result is

```
special variables
function variables
0:('2', '', '', '2', 'e3', ' ')
1:('20', '', '', '20', '', ' ')
2:('20.4', '20.4', '', '', '', ' ')
3:('45', '', '', '45', '', ' ')
4:('2', '', '', '2', 'e4', ' ')
len():5
```

I would like some help to undestand what is happening and if there is any way to get this done in a similar way that happen on the regexp.com.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [re.findall not returning full match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425386/re-findall-not-returning-full-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take care of it. (All the items are strings)

```
import re

st = '230FIC000.PV>=-2e3 211FIC00.PV <= 20 100fic>-20.4 tic200 >=45 tic100 <-2E-4 fic123 >1'

re.findall(r'-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(?:[Ee]\ *-?\ *[0-9]+)|-?\d+\.\d+|\b\d+\b', st)
```

referred: [How to extract numbers from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python),

[Extracting scientific numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152597/extract-scientific-number-from-string),

and [Extracting decimal values from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string)